# In substrate, does the genesis block get finalised the same way as the subsequent blocks?

Tags: consensus, grandpa

In substrate, does the genesis block get finalised the same way as the subsequent blocks, or is finalisation of the genesis block a special case?

Answer (score 9):

The first block is #0 (genesis block) and it is always considered finalized by default since it is explicitly defined as part of the chain spec, any subsequent blocks (#1 included) are treated equally and finalized with whatever consensus protocol the given chain provides (typically GRANDPA).